Adding events to each button in a loop C#
I need to add for each button an event for when it's clicked.
When the button is clicked it adds points to a SQL Data table, but that I can do on my own, I just need help on starting.
for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
{
     Button buttonWhite = new Button();
     //button settings
     buttonWhite.Tag = i;
     round1.Controls.Add(buttonWhite);

     Button buttonDraw = new Button();
     //button setting
     buttonDraw.Tag = i;
     round1.Controls.Add(buttonDraw);

     Button buttonBlack = new Button();
     //button settings
     buttonBlack.Tag = i;
     round1.Controls.Add(buttonBlack);
}

The number of buttons varies

Why can you not add the event within the loop?  buttonWhite.onClick = this.WhiteClick;, etc.?

How about something like the below? Values probably aren't right, but since you can do that part on your own, it is a working example of how to create a useable event on the fly.
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<int> matches = new List<int>() { 1,2,3 };
        round1.Size = new Size(1000, 1000);
        int x = 1;
        int y = 1;
        int buttonHeight = 20;
        int buttonWidth = 100;
        int pad = 25;
        for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
        {
            Button buttonWhite = new Button()
            {
                Location = new Point(x+(buttonWidth*i)+pad, x),
                Size = new Size(buttonWidth, buttonHeight),
                Text = $"Button{(i*3)+1}",
                Tag = i
            };
            round1.Controls.Add(buttonWhite);
            buttonWhite.Click += Button_Click;

            Button buttonDraw = new Button()
            {
                Location = new Point(x + (buttonWidth * i) + pad, x + pad),
                Size = new Size(buttonWidth, buttonHeight),
                Text = $"Button{(i*3)+2}", 
                Tag = i
            };
            round1.Controls.Add(buttonDraw);
            buttonDraw.Click += Button_Click;

            Button buttonBlack = new Button()
            {
                Location = new Point(x + (buttonWidth * i) + pad, x + (pad*2)),
                Size = new Size(buttonWidth, buttonHeight),
                Text = $"Button{(i*3)+3}", 
                Tag = i
            };
            round1.Controls.Add(buttonBlack);
            buttonBlack.Click += Button_Click;
        }
    }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int value = (int)((Button)sender).Tag;
        MessageBox.Show($"Add {value} to SQL Table here");            
    }

